# seach a barcode trough the excel file and add number in front of each barcode to count them by python programming

Tags: python, excel

i wanna count Goods inside a warehouse  by reading their barcodes using a handheld barcode scanner
i can read barcodes simply by using this code :

```
a = input()
```

i have an excel file (*.xlsx file) with all the barcode of goods like this :

[excel file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFjD1.png)

As you can see, i have to search all A1 to A(n)
(all rows in column [A] which is more than 4000 rows in origin file)
find the barcode address and add a number in corresponding cell front of it in cells B1 to B(n)

for example if i scan the barcode >>> 1142036176
search that number in A1 to A(n) rows and it will find it in cell A2, so for counting it, B2 is blank cell so, Because this cell is empty, it must write the number 1 in its corresponding cell,
but if i scan 1128059339 , it,s in A1 and it's corresponding counted number is in B1 that is 9 and it must turns to the 10

i haven,t any clue about how to do it and don,t know the syntax of commands for this purpose
can you give me a simple code that do the task?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work for you:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('sam2.xlsx',header=None)
n=input()
df[1]=df[1].fillna(0)
df.loc[df[0]==int(n),1]+=1
df.to_excel('sam2.xlsx',index=False,header=False)
```

Do comment if you face any error.
Here you need to pip install openpyxl to work with excel.

If you want to edit corresponding G column just change the index of column.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('sam2.xlsx',header=None)
n=input()
df[6]=df[6].fillna(0)
df.loc[df[0]==int(n),6]+=1
df.to_excel('sam2.xlsx',index=False,header=False)
```

This should solve your current problem.

Comment: i,m not working on CSV, I,m working on Excel file (***.xlsx files)

Comment: Sorry for the error, I have fixed the issue. Do accept the solution if its useful

Comment: it,s not working; 1st of all thanks for helping but i guess you didn't get the point of my problem i wanna to count the goods in warehouse by scan their barcodes by handheld barcode scanner; if i push the trigger of barcode scanner, the barcode value will transfer in 'n' variable and then i wanna search the value of variable 'n' in column A from A1 to A... and for example, if it found it in A237, check the number on it's corresponding cell in G column which is G237 in this example and add one number to it (if the value of G237 is 5, delete 5 & put 6 on it or if it's 7 delete it & put 8 on it)

Comment: @Hamid'Smith'Salehi In the question you asked me to update count in B column. Is the count present in G column? I'm updating corresponding B column where the bar code is found.

Comment: @Hamid'Smith'Salehi I have edited the code to change G column please check if it solves your problem.

Comment: yes, B or G, one of them. but the main question is : how to find the barcode in cells of column A and put the and read it's corresponding cell's value in B or G column (one of them) and +=1 the value (counting the barcode)

Comment: @Hamid'Smith'Salehi df.loc[df[0]==int(n),6]+=1 This line actualy finds the barcode and would increament the count of corresponding row. Please run the above code and check if its working or not.

Comment: @Hamid'Smith'Salehi Do Upvote the answer if it solved your problem :))

Comment: sorry i haven't 15 reputation or more to give you upvoting. but i marked your answer as correct answer. another question : if i wanna search through the C columns instead of A columns, can i do it by changing "all" zeros by 2 in the code?

Comment: Yes but make sure that bar code is present in C column. You have to change just this line:    df.loc[df[2]==int(n),6]+=1.   To be more clear you can print df to see how the values are stored and what is happening in the code.

Comment: thanks for perfect guide @kaylan-reddy , actually what if i wanna add an "" if "" to the code ? i mean i wanna do : if n found in df[2] : then do >>> df.loc[df[2]==int(n),6]+=1  else : print("barcode not found") . how can i do that ? all i want to add is just one "if" line to my code and i need the syntax of it (syntax of if line). thanks aagain

Comment: @Hamid'Smith'Salehi you can use:  if(n in df[2]): Do else: print("Barcode not found")

Comment: it,s not working, final code is : 

df=pd.read_excel('/path/test.xlsx',header=None)
df[6]=df[6].fillna(0)
n=input("SCAN Barcode : ")
while n != 0 :
    if (n in df[2]) :
        df.loc[df[2]==int(n),6]+=1
        df.to_excel('path/test.xlsx',index=False,header=False)
    else :
        print("Barcode not found")
    n=input("SCAN Barcode : ")                            how can i edit it to work? every barcodes that exist in excel i will imsert, i have "barcode not found" output and nothing else

Comment: i mean when i added that "if" that you suggested : "barcode not found" is all i get and it,s not working anymore

Comment: i still has issue with the code i changed, if you want to see more detail about my new problem, you can check this out : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72068303/wrong-output-in-a-python-code-for-search-and-count-the-scanned-barcodes-in-excel)