# wrong output in a python code for search and count the scanned barcodes in excel

Tags: python, excel

i have a xlsx file that it's "C" Column contains barcodes of things and i wanna to insert the barcodes to count them (number of each barcode will put in corresponding cell in "G" column)
the main issue is :
i want to receive a message that shown "Barcode not found" when the inserted barcode doesn't exist in any cells of column "C"

but i will give the output : "Barcode not found"  when i insert barcodes (for those which exist in "C" column or others Which aren,t).
i like to get "Barcode not found" when the inserted barcode doesn't exist in C column and continue asking for input

but i have this error when i insert a barcode that i'm sure exist :

any suggestions?

Comment: You would like to get a message 'Barcode found' for those already existing?

Comment: @YannisP. no, i like to get "Barcode not found"  when the inserted barcode doesn't exist in C column and continue asking for input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```py
from numpy import int64 # handle large integers
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import time


# df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(inp),sep=';')
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\dcg601\Downloads\test2.xlsx', header=None)
# df[2] = df[2].astype('int') # need to do that to enable comparisons
# df.iloc[:2]
df.iloc[:,6] = df.iloc[:,6].fillna(0)
df.iloc[:,2] = df.iloc[:,2].astype('str')
df.iloc[:,2] = df.iloc[:,2].str.strip('\u202a') # strips the right to left character
df.iloc[:,2] = df.iloc[:,2].astype('int64') # necessary cause numbers are too large

n = input("SCAN Barcode : ")
n = int64(n)
while n != 0 :
    if(n in df[2].values):
        df.loc[df[2]==int64(n),6]+=1
        df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\dcg601\Downloads\test2.xlsx',index=False,header=False)
    else :
        print("Barcode not found")
        time.sleep(5)
    print()
    n = input("SCAN Barcode : ")
    n = int64(n)
```

**Notes:**

1. `df[2] = df[2].astype('int')` otherwise comparisons fail. pandas default values are strings if I am not wrong,
2. After inputting you should cast ton integers with `n = int(n)`, otherwise `n` from the input is string,
3. The `if` condition should check `n in df[column].values` and not just `n in df[column]`.

**Edit**: added some `iloc`s but theyr probably not much necessary, made some strips and conversions to and from `str`

Comment: Good to know, continue posting your questions to SatckOverflow

Comment: when i test the code on test file, it worked but now that i tested it on main *.xlsx file, an error occured that says : invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\u202a1006044004'   it's related to the line : df[2] = df[2].astype('int')   because when i checked the numbers in C columns, they are class str numbers

Comment: and >>>>> i have another error too, related to the line :                                                                          df[6] = df[6].fillna(0)     and the error says :                                                                                 Exception has occurred: KeyError
6

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  File "/path/test.py", line 35, in <module>
    df[6] = df[6].fillna(0)

Comment: The first error comes I think from the fact that bar codes can be strings, right? `df[6]` can throw an error, if you have headers as column names, in the columns of your file. Then you should better write `df['column_name']` instead of df[6]

Comment: no, i deleted the headers, how can i fix the bugs? how can read the integer class of barcodes in rows of C column which are string, and what to do for another error??

Comment: It seems to be rather long to answer in a comment. There are probably some changes that need to be made, eg. to use `iloc[:,6]`, instead of `df[6]`. If you should accept strings in the input the condition in while should be modified, too. Debugging is a long discussion, I can't tell you very shortly how to do it. 
Would it be an option for you to edit your question and add some of your data, including values that contain characters? Otherwise, it is hard to really say what's going on.

Comment: Ok i will edit the question and put the excel file in it

Comment: i edited my question and you can check the file via the link upper than my code and see bugs and understand my problem better

Comment: It seems that the problem lies basically in right-to-left writing in some entries, Characters like '\u202a' seem to indicate exactly that thing. Your spreadsheet had some numbers aligned like they were written in that specific way, i.e. right to left. I am trying to strip those entries but you might encounter something more. Right now it seems to work...

Comment: i arranged from left to right and the link of .xlsx file has updated . and the problem occurre when inserting a barcode that exist in file

Comment: Your new file seems to have one column less. `df.iloc[:,6]` seems to fail.

Comment: i don't think so, i put the screenshot of the file in the answer, G column still is in Loc[:,6]

Comment: A quick hack was to fill column G with 0 and to rerun. Otherwise it needs a bit better pandas code ...

Comment: i did exactly this hack and done, it works, i filled all cells in G column and then run the code and now it works, thanks for your kindly support, i wish i could give you thousands of reputation for facing the challenges many time and always stay supporter, thanks man